# JS / JSX Script to generate unique PNGs from all permutations across all Photoshop Layer Groups and their Photoshop Layers

Tags: javascript, arrays, intervals, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm looking into getting into generative art. My idea is to have Photoshop (CS5) generate a *unique* PNG for *all* permutations that exist while the script iterates through every LAYER across each LAYER GROUP (layerSets).

As an example, it would be similar to a character generator where:
PARENT **layerSets** consist of parts or locations across the face/body (A,B)
CHILD **layers** consist of accessories/styles  (1,2,3)
Such that all generated PNG permutations would be: A1B1,A2B1,A3B1;A2B1,A2B2,A2B3;A3B1,A3B2,A3B3 only.  (A1A2, A2A3, A1A3; B1B2, B2B3, B1B3 are not necessary; Standalone A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3 are not necessary).

I've found some code from *@Mr.Online* that generates *random*, and potentially *redundant* combinations from user-inputted quantity. His script requires that all layers be hidden by the user prior to running.

Thanks so much. Hopefully this'll help:

```
function Visible() {
  var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets; // loops through all groups
  for(var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++){
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible=true;
    var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;
    var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);
    groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;
    Save();
  }
  Revert();
}

function Save() {
  var outFolder = app.activeDocument; // psd name
  var outPath = outFolder.path;
  var fName = "PNG";   // define folder name
  var f = new Folder(outPath + "/" + fName);
  if ( ! f.exists ) {
    f.create()
  }
  var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName +"/" + "Pattern_" +  num + ".png");
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

// Original code - revert function does not work
// for some users
//function Revert(){
//  var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
//  var desc300 = new ActionDescriptor();
//  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
//  var ref163 = new ActionReference();
//  var idSnpS = charIDToTypeID( "SnpS" );
//  ref163.putName( idSnpS, "test.psd" );
//  desc300.putReference( idnull, ref163 );
//  executeAction( idslct, desc300, DialogModes.NO );
//}

function Revert(){
   var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
   executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}

var count = prompt("How many patterns you want","");
for (var x=0 ; x<count;x++){
  var num = x+1;
  Visible();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you need to ignore the random layers. However, if you know the number of layers & groups it's quite straight forward:

```
show_layers("A", "1");
show_layers("B", "1");

function show_layers(g, n)
{
    // g is the name of the group (layerset)
    // n is the name of the layer (artlayer)
    srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.layerSets.getByName(g).artLayers.getByName(n);
    srcDoc.activeLayer.visible = true;
}
```

So, assuming all layers are switched off, you can **get** the layers by name and then make them visible.

Switching off *all* the layers is a bit more involved.  You have to loop over all groups and then loop over its sublayers. Working with groups is a bit of a learning curve.

```
function switch_off_all_layers(bool)
{
  var numLayers = app.activeDocument.layers.length;

  // want to hide the background as well?
  // default: background = visible
  if (bool == undefined) bool = false;
  if (bool == false)
  {
    numLayers -=1; // -1 for background
  }

  for(var i = 0 ; i < numLayers; i++) 
  {
    if (app.activeDocument.layers[i].typename == "LayerSet")
    {
      app.activeDocument.layers[i].visible = true;

      var subDoc = app.activeDocument.layers[i];
      var numOfSubLayers = subDoc.layers.length;

      for (var j = numOfSubLayers -1; j >= 0; j--)
      {
        var tempSubLayer = subDoc.layers[j];
        tempSubLayer.visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Further to my explanation, if you can't supply the group layers & names then  you fill want to loop over all groups and all layers.

```
var groupLayers = [];
var artLayers = [];
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);

alert("Group layers\n" + groupLayers);
alert("Art layers\n" + artLayers);

// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
   for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
   {
      var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
      
      // apply the function to layersets;
      if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")
      {
        if (theLayer.isBackgroundLayer == true)
        {   
            // add background layer (if needed)
            // artLayers.push(theLayer.name);
        }
        else
        {
            // find the art layers
            artLayers.push(theLayer.name);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // find the group layers
        groupLayers.push(theLayer.name);

        collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghoul Fool. I'm afraid I won't be able to quickly determine names and numbers of the Layer Groups and Layers.  Is there a way to have the script to do that for me?

Comment: @blackstallion I've added an recursive function to loop over all the layers - you should be able to work it out from there!